# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object On WordPress save_post acion hook

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin where I need to update the input field post meta when the actual post is updated. So here is my code:

```
function save_meta_function ( ) {
    global $post;       
    $post_id        =   $post->ID;  
    $meta_values    =   get_post_meta( $post_id );  
    foreach ($meta_values as $key => $value) {              
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $_POST[$key] );
    }   
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_function' );
```

but it's showing several errors:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object   // that's $post_id
>         =   $post->ID;

Can you tell me why `$post_id       =   $post->ID;` line showing that error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with follows -

```
function save_meta_function ( $post_id ) {
    $meta_values    =   get_post_meta( $post_id );  
    foreach ($meta_values as $key => $value) {              
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $_POST[$key] );
    }   
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_function' );
```

Comment: then where the variable `$post_id` comes from?

Comment: WordPress by default pass $post_id as first parameter in 'save_post' hook. For more info check ref. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/